# Disable Security during development in AspNet MVC environment

Tags: asp.net-mvc, security

I am looking for best practices around security configuration management in web application during development. I have 2 situations.

1. I have a bunch of functions (say REST APIs) that returns some data from the database. In production, the calling client will have to authenticate itself say against a AspNetMembership provider.
2. There is another set of functions where in the authenticated principal information is required to fetch the data.

During development the developer needs to setup security and https in IIS to make this happen. Is there best practices followed in Asp.Net or in other programming languages to disable security during development so that the developer does not have to setup security in local IIS server (not Cassini) where the application is hosted and also not supply credentials in header when debugging.

Answer (score 0):

The best practices would be not to allow security to be disabled.  If you're using Forms Authentication, security shouldn't need to be set up in IIS, just in the application, and Visual Studio easily lets you add a development certificate to enable HTTPS.

One last best practice:  Use ASP.NET Identity, not AspNetMembership for your identity provider.  AspNetMembership is legacy at this point, and does not follow modern security best practices.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I have heard from other sources that it is common practice to have security disabled during development and later at production deployment time Security is introduced as an Aspect. So I think there should ways to do this.